# SQL Server adding its own aliases and getting them wrong

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2014

I wrote the following short, simple view:

```
--DROP VIEW ReportObjects.vStarts;
CREATE VIEW ReportObjects.vStarts AS
SELECT *
FROM ReportObjects.vLotHistory
WHERE
        LotType = 'Some constant value'
    AND CDOName = 'Some constant value'
    AND SpecId = 'Some constant value'
```

When I execute this script then click "Design" on the view in SSMS, I get this:

```
SELECT ContainerName, SpecName, ProductName, LotStatus, CDOName, ResourceName AS LotType, EmployeeName AS WorkflowName, LotType AS DieQty, 
                  WorkflowName AS LotQty, DieQty AS TxnDate, LotQty AS TxnDateGMT, TxnDate AS ContainerId, TxnDateGMT AS HistoryMainlineId, ContainerId AS ProductId, 
                  HistoryMainlineId AS SpecId, ProductId AS WorkflowId, SpecId AS WorkflowBaseId, WorkflowId AS WorkflowStepId, WorkflowBaseId, WorkflowStepId, ResourceId, 
                  EmployeeId
FROM     ReportObjects.vLotHistory
WHERE  (LotType = 'Some constant value') AND (CDOName = 'Some constant value') AND (SpecId = 'Some constant value')
```

See the problem? `DieQty AS TxnDate, LotQty AS TxnDateGMT, TxnDate AS ContainerId`
It's aliasing `columnA` with the name of `columnC`!

I've tried dropping/recreating the view several times.
I know it can be argued that `SELECT *` is icky, but that's beside the point (and it *is* necessary sometimes in production code).

The view above is selecting from another view defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW ReportObjects.vLotHistory AS
SELECT
    lot.ContainerName,
    hist.SpecName,
    hist.ProductName,
    lot.Status LotStatus,
    hist.CDOName,
    hist.ResourceName,
    hist.EmployeeName,
    lot.csiLotType LotType,
    WorkFlowBase.WorkflowName,
    hist.Qty DieQty,
    hist.Qty2 LotQty,
    hist.TxnDate,
    hist.TxnDateGMT,
    lot.ContainerId,
    hist.HistoryMainlineId,
    hist.ProductId,
    hist.SpecId,
    Workflow.WorkflowId,
    Workflow.WorkflowBaseId,
    hist.WorkflowStepId,
    hist.ResourceId,
    hist.EmployeeId
FROM ODS.MES_Schema.Container lot
    LEFT JOIN ODS.MES_Schema.HistoryMainline hist
        ON lot.ContainerId = hist.ContainerId
    LEFT JOIN ODS.MES_Schema.WorkflowStep WS
        ON hist.WorkflowStepId = WS.WorkflowStepId
    LEFT JOIN ODS.MES_Schema.Workflow
        ON WS.WorkflowId = Workflow.WorkflowId
    LEFT JOIN ODS.MES_Schema.WorkflowBase
        ON WorkflowBase.WorkflowBaseId = Workflow.WorkflowBaseId
```

Does anyone know why SSMS or SQL Server is eating my query and spitting out nonsense? Note that I am not using SSMS tools to create the view -- I am using `CREATE VIEW` as shown above.

Comment: If you specify the exact columns and not just `Select *`, does same thing happen? Can you try to give alias to the *parent* view columns instead of the child?

Comment: I can't get what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I see two major problems here. First: you should not use select * in a view definition. When the underlying table changes you have to refresh the view or you will get unexpected (and quite strange) results. Second: you should NEVER create nested views. It seems totally logical but the performance is deplorable. It confuses the heck out of the optimizer and the execution plans are a nightmare.

Comment: Is the only problem one that occurs when you click "Design" on the view?   Or does the view actually return unexpected results?

Comment: @bonCodigo: When columns are explicitly selected, the problem does not seem to occur.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: The problem is that MSSQL is making aliases for columns but using names from the wrong columns; e.g. "LotType AS DieQty" is selecting a human-readable text field and naming if after a numeric quantity (which is the name of another column selected later in the query).

Comment: @CharlesBurns, can you clarify if this is just a GUI issue in the design, or if when you do the actual execution of the query, you are getting incorrect results?  If the former, I'm guessing it's just a UI bug.

Comment: @Greg, @TabAlleman: Unfortunately the query returns no rows (legitimately) because the data hasn't yet been created.
I made another view with one less `WHERE` condition to test, but no aliases were created by SQL Server. I know this is almost too weird to have happened, but I swear that myself and a coworker recreated the original view numerous times and it happens every time, but only with that view.

Comment: @SeanLange: Thanks for the tip on nested views. As for the `SELECT *`, it isn't necessary in this case but I have seen [rare] cases where it's legitimately required. The view with the `SELECT *` queries only from another view, so we have full control over what it returns.

Comment: @Charles: On your last comment "we have full control over what it returns" -- only to a point. The definition of the view is cached -- if you change an underlying view, SQL server doesn't know to flush and refresh the parent view definition and then you run into issues like you have asked about. This is why Sean suggests never using `SELECT *`. You shouldn't wrap an unknown result set into a view because they're not as dynamic as you think, so the results are not guaranteed. Client applications relying on `SELECT *` should probably query the underlying tables directly instead.

Comment: Select * in a view by definition is NEVER required. A view is NOT dynamic and will not change the returned columns when the underlying table changes. You either need to create the view with schemabinding or execute sp_refreshview when the base table changes. From the MS documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx "If a view is not created with the SCHEMABINDING clause, sp_refreshview should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view that affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might produce unexpected results when it is queried."

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, @Sean, thank you for the additional tips on MSSQL's internal view handling. Additionally, I now agree regarding `SELECT *` in views. The situations in which `SELECT *` was required in my experience did not involve views, but dynamic SQL generation of tables that had analogous staging/logging tables. It looks like in my rush I assumed that it would be just fine in a view, as well, but that's probably what caused the problem. If one of you posts your explanation as an answer, I'll mark them accordingly. Thanks!